# retrieve the key of keyword directly in Dreamweaver in SDL Tridion 2011 Sp1

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I have a Keyword field in my component "somefield". It has one key and Value.

```
key: msg
Value: message
```

Is it possiblt to retrieve the key value of a keyword directly in DreamWeaver.

Can any one help me on that

Thanks in adavance

Comment: Is this question a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509454/how-should-i-get-keyword-key-from-dwt/12512198 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sample code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908803/how-to-get-the-keyword-from-category-name-in-c-sharp-tbb) to get keywords.Push them to package using c# tbb or use the logic in custom function.

Answer (score 5):

In Dreamweaver it is not possible to do this directly. You need to use the TOM.NET API to get the key and place it into the package.  Then you can use the package item in your Dreamweaver TBB.

Comment: Alternatively you can write a custom function source that you **can** call from your Dreamweaver TBB directly.